# How did people write end-user software in Smalltalk?

Tags: history, smalltalk

There is something I've never understood about Smalltalk, since reading about it in a book when I was a child, tho' I have never used it "in anger". I know that it is turtles-all-the-way-down, that you can break into the program at any time, inspect the state of your objects, even change the code, and resume running. This is obviously a dream come true for a researcher, whether in CS or in industry, an engineer simulating a system, an analyst modelling a market, and so on. I also know that there was no concept of writing source in text files and compiling them into a binary, the editor and the runtime are the same thing. But how do you deliver software to an end user who wouldn't know a debugger if it bit them on the nose, and couldn't care less what an object is? Was there a secret keystroke to turn all those features off and make it behave like "normal" software? Or was Smalltalk software only ever sold to sophisticated users who were programmers too?

Comment: How is this "opinion based"? Surely there are people who have actually done this, who can explain how it works?

Comment: I don't get the reason to close. I don't think whether or not users were sophisticated is the key to this question, but more of a commentary.

Comment: I am also curious who the customers were, other programmers, or retail consumers, say

Comment: Can you cite a source?  My understanding of Smalltalk is it's like a lot of other languages that have interactive tools like debuggers, IDE, and a REPL, that developers primarily work in, but can also compile standalone programs.  Certainly most modern Smalltalk dialects work that way.

Comment: Am I the only one that doesn't understand this question???

Comment: The question was, was the entire Smalltalk environment shipped with every app, and Jorg's answer below clarifies things for me - Smalltalk *does* make a distinction between development mode and deployment mode.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I think the source of confusion is that the original  versions of Smalltalk (e.g. Smalltalk 80) weren't like that: the language was essentially a self-hosting operating system with integrated development tools, and no method AIUI of deploying a standalone application (the tools were an integral part of the OS). As most academic descriptions of Smalltalk focus on these early versions, most people aren't really aware of how the language evolved later.

Comment: @Jules, see my answer below. The SystemTracer object in Smalltalk-80 could winnow an image so that only the parts that were essential to an application were written out to an image, which could then be run without the debugger, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Or was Smalltalk software only ever sold to sophisticated users who were programmers too?

No. It's the other way around: Smalltalk was designed so that every user can be a programmer, without *needing* to be sophisticated. In fact, Smalltalk was designed for *children*.

The basic idea is that a user would read a manual about the length of a middle-sized undergrad college textbook in order to use sophisticated machinery. Say, you are a carpenter and buy a CNC machine, you wouldn't expect to be able to use it right away, but you also wouldn't expect to need years to learn how to use it. You would probably expect to read about 10000 to 100000 lines of manual and learn about a couple of days to a couple of weeks.

For a software system, the ultimate manual is the source code. So, in order to be usable, the software system should consist of no more than 100000 lines of code, so that the user can read all of them. (And it should be written in such a way and such a language that she can understand it.) That's the goal of Smalltalk: the original Smalltalk system was about 60000 lines of code for *everything*, the "OS", the hardware drivers, the VM, the compiler, the interpreter, the IDE, the debugger, the editor, an office suite, a distributed document management system, etc. In the 1970s, that was the best they could do, today, 40 years later, we have much better languages available, and the replacement system and language(s) that Alan Kay's team are working on currently, is expected to be less than 20000 lines for the same feature set. (Compare that to e.g. Windows, which has 50 *million* lines.)

That was the idea. How well that idea worked, well … judge for yourself :-)

Modern Smalltalks try to make a distinction between development and deployment. Basically, you define some application root object, the system traces the connections between all objects in the system, and copies out only those objects which are directly or indirectly connected to the root application object, leaving you with a streamlined image that contains only the application and the libraries and frameworks needed by it.

You typically also don't edit the running system directly, but use some kind of version control system (e.g. Monticello) that stores your modifications as a series of semantic changes to the system and thus can be replayed on a different system. There is also research into module systems and package management systems, and most modern Smalltalks have at least one of the two.

So, the way that Smalltalk systems are deployed *today* is that there is some minimal "clean" image, and you apply CVS changesets or install packages or link modules on top of that, which yields an image which is specialized just for that application. If you want to do development, you start with a development image which includes the editor, compiler, IDE, etc. and apply those same changes on top of that.

The languages that came after Smalltalk (e.g. Self, Newspeak) often included a textual serialization format for code (Smalltalk itself doesn't have syntax for classes or methods, because they are created programmatically by the IDE (e.g. creating a class is actually just calling the `subclass` method on some class which will return a class which is a subclass of the class the method was called on); it only has syntax for expressions and statements.), that could be used to "file in" classes and methods into the system, and modern Smalltalks also have that capability.

Comment: "Smalltalk was designed so that every user can be a programmer" meanwhile at my Grandma's: "Sonny, my googles ain't workin' again!"

Answer (score 3):

One point that Jörg did not mention in his answer: After the "deployment" step it is actually hard to tell that an application was written in Smalltalk, because the IDE was either stripped out or hidden. For example, try these:

http://scratch.mit.edu/scratch_1.4/

http://www.planet-plopp.com/english/download.html

Also, just by looking at the range of applications built with Smalltalk, you can tell that their users are certainly no programmers nowadays:
https://twitter.com/hashtag/thingsPeopleBuiltWithSmalltalk

That every user should be able to modify their software is a Smalltalk idea that still has not made it to the mainstream (while many other of its ideas are commonplace nowadays - like GUIs or Object-Orientation).

Comment: Again, object-oriented programming is not an idea that came from Smalltalk.  The term did, but the concepts came from Simula, which does it a very different way.  In the years since Alan Kay coined the phrase, Simula-style OOP has taken over the world, and Smalltalk-style OOP (message passing, etc) has failed every time it was introduced in the marketplace of ideas.

Comment: I wouldn't call JavaScript or Objective-C or Python or Ruby a failure, exactly. Even the Java VM has invokedynamic now, which makes it support Smalltalk-style OOP for various languages running on top of it. Dynamic languages definitely are mainstream now and still on the rise, even if they may not be the most popular yet.

Comment: JavaScript and Objective-C are both "successful" by riding the coattails of a popular platform.  But nobody uses Obj-C outside the Apple ecosystem, and just look how popular other (Simula-style) OO languages that compile down to JavaScript are becoming.  (I used the term "marketplace of ideas" for a reason. Monopolies play by different rules.)  Ruby was a fad that was popular for a while, but that's fading now that people are learning (again) why message-passing OOP sucks.  And Python has no support for "missing method" and no good mechanism to implement it, so is that really Smalltalk-style?

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, I'm not sure why you dismiss Ruby and message passing. Certainly, the concept of message-passing is done in modern operating systems, like Mach.

Comment: @MasonWheeler "Smalltalk style OOP (message passing, etc.) has failed every time it was introduced in the marketplace of ideas." Are Objective C, macOS UI, and iOS failures? Python? Microservices?

Comment: Python I already mentioned above.  It doesn't actually fit what we're talking about here, so I'm not sure why it's being brought up *again.*  And microservices... blech.  They're a stupid idea that I hope ends up being nothing more than a passing fad.  All they do is move complexity around from one place to another, without doing much of anything to actually reduce it.

Answer (score 2):

In the classic Smalltalk-80, there was a SystemTracer that we at Tektronix used to "strip" an image for deployment.

Basically, it performed a full traversal of the system from a single specified point, excluding the global SystemDictionary and its contents.

This way, you could run SystemTracer on your application (typically, a Contoller subclass), and it would drag everything else in with it, but not stuff like Context or other classes and distinguished objects that were not involved in the operation of your application.